# Can other words replace "consideration" in "with all due consideration"?

Tags: word-usage

The following is a multiple choice question in an English test:

> The employers prepared, with all due _______, for a conference with the Trade Union.
>
> A. *caution*
>
> B. *concern*
>
> C. *certainty*
>
> D. *consideration*

I feel A ("with all due caution") is ok, but I am not sure.

Comment: 'A' would seem to me the only one which properly fits.

Comment: I'd choose D. (Consideration: care, solicitude)

Comment: @Josh61: It really depends on exactly how the employers *actually* prepared, which obviously we can only guess at. But apparently on average the standard construction *with all due XXX* is [more likely to occur with **caution**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+all+due+consideration%2Cwith+all+due+caution&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20all%20due%20consideration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20all%20due%20caution%3B%2Cc0). No answer is "right" - so it's a stupid test, and a POB question.

Comment: Not sure - normally "with due ___" would be "caution", or "respect" (which was not one of the options), but in this context, how does one "prepare with caution"? Were they expecting an attack prior to the conference? If they're preparing for a conference, they would probably want to consider all the possible angles that the discussion might take - so I agree with the above commenters that it's *probably* D.

Comment: E. with due -diligence

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ***caution***. Why? Because I can find the phrase [on the internet](http://xueshirleydong152369.blogspot.com) in a context completely unrelated to multiple-choice questions.

- Caution (n.) great care which you take in order to avoid possible danger. E.g. the employers prepared, with all due caution, for a conference with the Trade Unions.

Having found the *"answer"* by cheating, let me say further that I see no reason why *"consideration"* isn't an equally good answer.

Whoever prepared this test was **_____**.

A. incompetent
B. lazy
C. rushed
D. sadistic

Answer (score 0):

- '*C*' is almost certainly *not* the correct answer. It is only acceptable if the intended emphasis is on the employers' correctness in being sure that the meeting will occur.
- '*A*' is possible, but it ought to be used when there is an actually anticipated danger of some kind.

At first glance '*B*' and '*D*' are nearly equally acceptable as an answer.  But '*B*', *concern*,  is closer in meaning to '*A*', *caution*, than '*D*', *consideration*, is to '*A*'.  **So that makes '*B*' less appropriate than '*D*' in almost all situations.**  However it should be noted that this same condition makes '*B*' a valid answer when '*A*' is valid.

Yes, all the answers are potentially correct, though '*C*' is least probable and '*D*' is most probable.

I would hope this is not too confusing--I take the first two items (marked by bullet points) as fundamental assumptions.  From there I weight the relative likelihood of each of answers ultimately corresponding to the answer the test writer(s) had in mind.

**To put it another way, I start by essentially ruling out *C* then *A*.  I conclude that of the remaining answers *B* is less appropriate than *D*.**

Comment: Your answer is confusing, it appears you are saying that any of the options are possible. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I chose "caution" instead of "consideration" because I feel the phrase  "with..." should be able to be used where "with all due..." is used, though their meanings are not completely the same. They are of basically the same structure and the only difference is that some extra meaning is added in the latter.

Now compare:
1.They prepared for the conference with caution.
2.They prepared for the conference with consideration(concern).

Aparently, there is nothing wrong with sentence 1. However, something seems to be lacking in sentence 2 and one may wonder: with consideration to what? or with concern for what?

Am I right? Looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIncrement is correct in saying that options A and B are very similar in meaning and option C is almost certainly wrong.

In my view, this information is enough to deduce that the correct answer is D. Of course, the correct word depends largely on the intended meaning, of which we cannot be certain. However, assuming that this multiple-choice test has exactly one correct answer for each question, we can deduce the following about the correct answer to the test:

Since options A and B are so similar in meaning, it would not be reasonable to award a mark for option A but not for option B, and vice versa. Hence, neither A nor B is correct. Then, since certainty is not a choice and therefore cannot be expected from the employers, to say that they prepared with all 'due' certainty seems absurd to me. We can therefore rule out option C and conclude that D must be the answer the examiner is looking for.